# Plugging a 65W computer power plug into a 45W step down transformer

Tags: power-supply, transformer, watts

Is it safe? Would it only charge slower, or could it damage anything?

Here is the setup in more detail:
I'm in Europe, where plugs are 230V.
My computer was bought in the US, so it's a 110V appliance.
I have a step down transformer 230V-110V, with a 45W wattage.
My computer power plug has a 65W wattage.

Thank you.

Comment: Consumer electronics support is off topic. Lucky for you the answer was already given so no harm. I wish you luck.

Comment: Wrong answer. Duh.

Comment: A friend of mine some time ago tried doing *exactly* what you are asking about, despite my insisting to not do it and that the laptop's power brick would be fine plugged directly into the AC outlet. The transformer burned out and let out a fairly large amount of smoke, but no open flame and no other damage. My friend learned the lesson, but at a cost.

Comment: Ahahahah, lame.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No.

If the computer requires 65 W and your transformer can only handle 45 W, then various bad things could happen.  The transformer could saturate or overheat or have the output voltage sag.  Too low a voltage is not good for the computer either.  It should not be damaged if properly designed, but might not turn on at brownout voltage or abruptly shut down when it needs the extra power.

However, check whether your computer really is 110 V only.  Most modern machines use "universal" input power supplies that can usually run from 90-260 V AC at 50-60Hz.  If this is the case, all you need is a localized line cord.

Comment: Aw, thanks. My charger actually uses a universal input power supply. I'm not sure what you mean by localized line cord. Can I just plug the US plug into a EU adapter?

Comment: @hkcktk: Devices that can handle universal power usually have detachable line cords.  Different line cords are availalbe for different countries.  They all have the same 3 prong interface at the device end with the other end "localized" to the standard of the particular country.  Line cords for the local area should be readily available.  If your device does not have a removable line cord, then it's unlikely to have a universal power input.

Comment: Oh now I see what you mean. Great. And it does have a removable line cord. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Most external laptop power bricks produced in the last 5 years have been universal - that is they accept 100-240V 50-60Hz with no issue. I would check your power supply to see if this is the case - you can normally just use a plug adapter. If you need help, take a picture of the power supply.

If not, the answer is not as clear-cut. Most laptop manufacturers have a range of power supplies - say a 20W for netbooks, a 40W for portables, a 60W for most laptops, and a 120W for mobile workstations. You will receive the size up from that required by your laptop i.e. a 25W laptop would often have a 40W power supply.

The problem is that it is difficult for a consumer to tell how much power their laptop is drawing. Worst case is usually charging an almost empty battery, whilst accessing the hard drive with the display at full brightness, running something graphics and processor intensive. There are always edge cases you may not find where it draws more.

It is awkward for a consumer to measure current draw. Not impossible, but not trivial.

Another complexity is the step down transformer. These do not behave gracefully when overloaded. They tend to saturate, overheat, and the voltage will sag. This then causes your power supply to get hot as well.

If your power supply is not 100-240V, then I would suggest the cheapest solution is to buy an entire new power supply from Kensington, Belkin or whoever.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed. I would've marked you as right answer, but I already marked the first one I received.

Answer (score 0):

The transformer may overheat when the laptop battery is dead, but as it charges up it will not require the full power, so it will work. The secondary windings are often AWG40 so the failure mode is often, it to go open circuit if the current in the secondary is exceeded by the power rating. It is safe but unreliable.

Do not operate while charging until it has reach full charge, then you may be able to sustain it or better, **get a Universal 100~240Vac laptop charger that works anywhere.**  on any laptop.. These universal chargers are typically fifty cents ($0.50) per watt output from reputable small electronic or Big Box stores. Anything more is just profit. Your charger must be a dinosaur as the cost of universal compliance is pennies more in volume.

Hope that helped (HTH) ;)